# How do I wait for an executable to open before continuing the code in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, shell, event-handling, wmi, executable

<sup>**Editor's note**:

This question is about an event-based way to run PowerShell code whenever a new process (possibly with a given executable name) is created *system-wide*.</sup>

I have done a ton of research and I can't seem to find any solutions to this.

I have tried using `Wait-Event -SourceIdentifier "ProcessStarted"`, but it doesn't seem to work at all. It just waits infinitely and does not make the code resume. If there is a way to wait for an executable to start or wait for a specific one to start, help a brother out!

Comment: Can you name a specific executable?  Please help us reproduce the problem, see: [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Can you share the event handler registration code you've used?

Comment: @iRon There is no need in any specific executable file. All I'm asking for is a method to wait for an executable file or program to open before continuing the script

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I don't understand why you need that, my question is simple and should take one line to reproduce. I already showed you the line of code I tried to wait for an executable file to open, and it didn't work. Literally all I'm asking for is a way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

From what I gather you have a script and want to pause it until a certain process starts and once it starts continue with the rest of the script.

A quick and dirty solution would be to use `get-process` and query the process name, in this example I use `vlc`. Ouput will  be `$null` until process is launched and once it's launched loop will exit. This would only work if the process is not already running. For example, if you are running Chrome already and you are trying to look for a new instance of the process this code won't work.

```
# some code
$processName = "vlc"
# wait until process starts
while ((Get-Process -name $processName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -eq $null)
{
    write-host "waiting for process to start to continue"
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 2
}

# continue code 
write-host "Process started"
```

--

Example output

```
.\wait_for_process.ps1
waiting for process to start to continue
waiting for process to start to continue
waiting for process to start to continue
waiting for process to start to continue
Process started
```

Answer (score 1):

The OS is not magically going to announce process start events to you - you need to specify what exact events you want to know about and then register for the target event:

```
# define an event polling query - this will poll WMI for new process creations every 2 seconds
$processCreationEventQuery = "SELECT TargetInstance FROM __InstanceCreationEvent WITHIN 2 WHERE TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_Process'"

# add event registration to make PowerShell consume the event from WMI
Register-CimIndicationEvent -Query $processCreationEventQuery -SourceIdentifier ProcessStarted
```

Now that we have an event registration set up, `Wait-Event` will work:

```
Wait-Event -SourceIdentifier ProcessStarted
```

---

If you want to wait for a more specific process to launch, modify the query filter, eg:

```
$processCreationEventQuery = @"
SELECT TargetInstance 
  FROM __InstanceCreationEvent 
WITHIN 2 
 WHERE TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_Process'
   AND TargetInstance.Name LIKE '%RelevantProcessNameGoesHere%'
"@
```

Comment: Nice; to add some context: Unlike the dedicated [`Win32_ProcessStartTrace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/krnlprov/win32-processstarttrace) event, this `__InstanceCreationEvent`-based approach is based on _periodic polling_, which means that short-lived processes that are both created and terminate _between_ polling intervals (`1` second is the minimum) are missed (which may or may not matter in practice). However, the `__InstanceCreationEvent` approach has the advantage that it does not require elevation (running with admin privileges).

Answer (score 0):

To complement [Mathias R. Jessen's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75897020/45375):

The **`__InstanceCreationEvent`-based approach shown there** is based on ***periodic polling***, which means that **short-lived processes may be *missed***, namely those that are both created and terminate *between* polling intervals (`1` second is the minimum) - this may or may not matter in practice.

- [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75933266/45375) shows a manual polling loop (no CIM/WMI events involved) with sub-second resolution, as well as `__InstanceCreationEvent` sample code that processes events indefinitely.

However, the `__InstanceCreationEvent` approach has the advantage that it does *not* require *elevation* (running with admin privileges), unlike the dedicated **[`Win32_ProcessStartTrace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/krnlprov/win32-processstarttrace) event**, which *does*.

***If running with elevation is an option***, the advantage of **`Win32_ProcessStartTrace`** is that it **does *not* miss events**; also, it is easier to set up.

---

Here's a **self-contained `Win32_ProcessStartTrace` sample** based on [`Register-CimIndicationEvent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/cimcmdlets/register-cimindicationevent) and [`Wait-Event`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/wait-event) that processes events indefinitely (press <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd> to stop) - as noted, **elevation is required**:

```bash
#requires -RunAsAdmin

Write-Verbose -Verbose "Monitoring for new processes; press Ctrl-C to exit..."
try {

  # Note: This registers for *any* new process.
  #       To limit the scope, pass a -Query argument instead of -ClassName; e.g.:
  #       -Query 'Select * From Win32_ProcessStartTrace Where ProcessName = "cmd.exe"'
  Register-CimIndicationEvent -ClassName Win32_ProcessStartTrace -SourceIdentifier ProcessStarted

  # Wait for and process events indefinitly.
  while ($true) {
    ($evt = Wait-Event -SourceIdentifier ProcessStarted) | Remove-Event
    # $evt.SourceEventArgs.NewEvent contains the event details.
    # For demo purposes, print them here.
    $evt.SourceEventArgs.NewEvent | Out-Host
  }
}
finally {
  UnRegister-Event -SourceIdentifier ProcessStarted
}
```

---

Here's a **variant** that uses the **`-Action` parameter** to **perform event processing *in the background*, which enables foreground activity *in parallel*** - but note that event processing only happens *between* PowerShell statements; it is blocked during long-running commands, including .NET method calls:

```bash
#requires -RunAsAdmin

Write-Verbose -Verbose "Monitoring for new processes; press Ctrl-C to exit..."
try {

  # Pass the event-handler code to the -Action parameter.
  # Register-CimIndicationEvent then creates and returns an event job that must later be removed.
  # If your -Action block were to produce *data* to communicate to the main thread, you'd have to
  # to use Receive-Job in the main thread.
  $eventJob = 
    Register-CimIndicationEvent `
         -ClassName Win32_ProcessStartTrace `
         -Action {
           # For demo purposes, simply print the event details to the console (host).
           $EventArgs.NewEvent | Out-Host
          }

  # You can now perform other operations here in the foreground,
  # but note that event processing happens only *between* PowerShell
  # statements.
  while ($true) {
    Write-Host . -NoNewline       # simulate foreground activity
    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 100 # sleep a little
  }

}
finally {
  # Remove the event job, which also unsubscribes from the CIM event.
  Remove-Job -Force $eventJob
}
```