# How do I wait for an application to start without administrator permissions in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, process, wait

This is a question I asked before: [How do I wait for an executable to open before continuing the code in PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75890935/)

I found a working solution, but it required administrative permissions. I was wondering if there was any way to do this without administrative permissions..

The main thing I'm trying to accomplish is a replacement for `Register-CimIndicationEvent`, but without any administrative permissions.

If you have any ideas to do this, I would greatly appreciate it!

I have already tried using `Register-CimIndicationEvent -ClassName 'Win32_ProcessStartTrace' -SourceIdentifier "ProcessStarted"`, but it requires administrative permissions to work.

I also tried:

```
$Q = "Select * from win32_ProcessStartTrace where processname = 'Process.exe'"

Register-CimIndicationEvent -Query $q -SourceIdentifier Q -Action {Stop-Process $event.SourceEventArgs.newevent.processID}
```

The code above supposedly closes a process every time it opens, which is my main goal. If you could help me to do something like that without administrative permissions, I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, **monitoring [`Win32_ProcessStartTrace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/krnlprov/win32-processstarttrace) CIM/WMI events requires *elevation*** (running as admin) -  [`Register-CimIndicationEvent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/cimcmdlets/register-cimindicationevent) reports an `Access denied` error on attempting to register an event handler from a non-elevated session.

- [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75943255/45375) shows `Win32_ProcessStartTrace` sample code (which therefore requires elevation).

As a **suboptimal workaround for *non-elevated* code**, you can **implement an (infinite) *polling loop* which periodically monitors the list of all processes for new additions** based on their start time, but note the following:

- To avoid excessive CPU load, you must *sleep* between polling operations, using [`Start-Sleep`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/start-sleep)
- There is therefore a chance that you'll *miss* the creation of short-lived processes, i.e. those that were both created *and terminated* while you're sleeping.
- Adjust the sleep interval to find the right balance between CPU load and potentially missing processes.
- Note that if your intent is really to *kill* new processes with [`Stop-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/stop-process), the only process you'll be permitted to kill are *your own, non-elevated* processes.

```bash
Write-Verbose -Verbose "Monitoring for new processes; press Ctrl-C to exit..."
$timestamp = [datetime]::Now
while ($true) {
  # Get all processes that were launched since the last (successful)
  # polling operation.
  $newPs = 
    [System.Diagnostics.Process]::GetProcesses().
    Where({ $_.StartTime -gt $timestamp })
  if ($newPS) { # At least 1 new process found.
    # Work with $newPS.Id here, for instance.
    # For demo purposes, the new processes are simply printed here.
    $newPs | Out-Host
    Write-Host '-----------'
    # Update the timestamp based on the most recently launched process.
    $timestamp = ($newPS | Measure-Object -Maximum -Property StartTime).Maximum
  }
  # Sleep a little, to avoid excessive CPU load.
  Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 50
}
```

---

**Alternative, using the [`__InstanceCreationEvent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/bb404681(v=vs.90)) CIM/WMI class**:

- Use of this class does *not* require elevation, but it too uses a *polling* mechanism that can cause it to miss creation of short-lived processes.
- The *minimum* polling interval is *1 second*.

```bash
Write-Verbose -Verbose "Monitoring for new processes; press Ctrl-C to exit..."
try {

  $query = '
    SELECT TargetInstance FROM __InstanceCreationEvent 
    WITHIN 1 WHERE 
    TargetInstance ISA "Win32_Process"
  '

  Register-CimIndicationEvent -ErrorAction Stop -Query $query -SourceIdentifier ProcessStarted

  while ($true) {
    ($e = Wait-Event -SourceIdentifier ProcessStarted) | Remove-Event
    # Get the PID (process ID) from the event
    $procId = $e.SourceEventArgs.NewEvent.TargetInstance.Handle
    # Sample processing: print the properties of the process.
    Get-Process -Id $procId | Format-List
  }
}
finally {
  UnRegister-Event ProcessStarted
}
```